# How to copy element into clipboard using Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js

I created a Nuxt webpage with Vuetify.js that generates an Email signature from a form to fill in. The render of the signature is displayed in a `v-card` element. I have added a `v-btn` to automatically copy the signature into the clipboard of the user, but I have some issues with it...

I tried to use `nuxt-clipboard2` from npm to help me doing this but nothing works...

Is anyone knows how to use this package correctly or have an alternative to copy content into the clipboard with Nuxt.js?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT

Here's my code:

```html
<template>
    <v-container fluid>

        <div class="display-3">Email signature</div>

        <signForm></signForm>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-container>
            <v-row justify="center" align="center">
                <v-col md="12">
                    <v-row justify="center" align="center">
                        <v-card color="fafafa" class="pa-3">
                            <signTemplate ref="foo"></signTemplate>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-row>
                </v-col>
                <v-btn class="ma-2" @click="copySign" tile>
                    <v-icon left>mdi-content-copy</v-icon>Copy the signature
                </v-btn>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>

    </v-container>
</template>


<script>
import signTemplate from '~/components/SignTemplate.vue'
import signForm from '~/components/signForm.vue'

export default {
  methods: {
    async copySign() {
        try {
            await this.$copyText(foo);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
  },
  components: {
      signTemplate,
      signForm
  }
}
</script>
```

EDIT #2

Here's the `signTemplate.vue`code.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-variant-ligatures: normal; orphans: 2; widows: 2; border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 480px; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: normal;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 10px 0px 12px; width: 160px; vertical-align: top;">
                        <a href="https://junior-entreprises.com/" target="_blank" style="background-color: transparent; color: rgb(51, 122, 183);">
                            <img border="0" alt="Logo" width="141" src="https://junior-entreprises.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Logo-50-ans-JE-site.png" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle; width: 141px; height: auto;">
                        </a>
                        </td>
                        <td style="font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 6px 0px; width: 320px;">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: transparent;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(61, 60, 63);"> {{this.$store.getters["getSignFirstName"]}} {{this.$store.getters["getSignLastName"]}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 11px; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(61, 60, 63);">{{this.$store.getters["getSignJob"]}} {{this.$store.getters["getSignDiv"]}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(155, 155, 155);"><font style="font-size: 12px;">tel: 01.43.70.26.56</font></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(155, 155, 155);"><font style="font-size: 12px;">mobile: {{this.$store.getters["getSignPhone"]}}</font></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(155, 155, 155);"><font style="font-size: 12px;">email: <span style="color: rgb(23, 147, 210);"><span style="color: rgb(183, 26, 81);"><a href="mailto:" target="_blank">{{this.$store.getters["getSignEmail"]}}</a></span></span></font></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(155, 155, 155);"><font style="font-size: 12px;">6 Rue des immeubles Industriels</font></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(155, 155, 155);"><font style="font-size: 12px;">75011, Paris</font></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="margin: 0px; padding: 6px 0px 0px;">
                                            <span style="display: inline-block; height: 22px;">
                                                <a href="https://fr-fr.facebook.com/junior.entreprises/" target="_blank" style="background-color: transparent; color: rgb(51, 122, 183);"><img alt="Facebook icon" border="0" width="23" height="23" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator/elegant-logo/fb.png" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></a>
                                                <a href="https://fr.linkedin.com/company/conf-d-ration-nationale-des-junior-entreprises" target="_blank" style="background-color: transparent; color: rgb(51, 122, 183);"><img alt="LinkedIn icon" border="0" width="23" height="23" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator/elegant-logo/ln.png" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></a>
                                                <a href="https://twitter.com/cnje" target="_blank" style="background-color: transparent; color: rgb(51, 122, 183);"><img alt="Twitter icon" border="0" width="23" height="23" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator/elegant-logo/tt.png" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></a>
                                                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/cnje/" target="_blank" style="background-color: transparent; color: rgb(51, 122, 183);"><img alt="Instagram icon" border="0" width="23" height="23" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator/elegant-logo/it.png" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></a>
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 13px; margin: 0px; padding: 8px 0px 0px; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(183, 26, 81); width: 480px; color: rgb(155, 155, 155); text-align: center;">Avec le soutiens de nos partenaires premiums: <a href="https://group.bnpparibas/" target="_blank">BNP Paribas</a>, <a href="https://www.alten.fr/" target="_blank">Alten</a>, <a href="https://www.ey.com/fr/fr/home" target="_blank">EY</a> et <a href="https://particuliers.engie.fr/" target="_blank">Engie</a>.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

EDIT #3

Here's a screenshot of what looks like my page right now. I would like to copy all the signature that is inside the `v-card` element by clinking on the button "Selectionner la signature".

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code?

Comment: I have edited my question to add my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue ref is not correctly used. Take a look [at the doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

Try to replace by this:
`await this.$copyText(this.$refs.foo)`

But are-you sure `ref` on the component `signTemplate` contains text you want to copy? Why not using `v-model`?

**Edit:**
If you want to copy the html content of your child component `signTemplate`, you can use `await this.$copyText(this.$refs.foo.$el.innerHTML)`. If you want only text, use `innerText`. This is vanilla javascript...

Comment: You're probably right, the Vue ref doesn't contain the formated text I want to copy... When I try to replace by `await this.$copyText(this.$refs.foo)` the value copy to the clipboard is `[object Object]`. 

Do you think if I pass my the `v-model` this will work? I will try now :)

Comment: In `copySign` method, place `console.log(this.$refs.foo)` to see in console devtools whats your Object contain. But I think it's a `VueComponent`.
Try this `await this.$copyText(this.$refs.foo.textContent)` but it's not a good practice to do like that...

Comment: By passing by `this.$refs.foo.$refs.textContent` I obtain only text without format...
And after exploring the response of `console.log(this.$refs.foo)` I think is not possible to copy the formatted content in this way...

Comment: Do know if it possible to process another way by only pre-selected the content and let the user process the `crtl+c`? I already view this case on this [website](https://design.sepefrei.fr/) by clicking on the button at the end of the form.

Comment: `this.$refs.foo.$refs.textContent`? You mean `this.$refs.foo.textContent`.   You can also access data with `this.$refs.foo.$data`. Publish the code of the `signTemplate` component to provide more information, it'll be easier to answer...

Comment: Ouch, signTemplate is a very ulgly component with many bad practice. Sorry. Anyway, which value do you want to copy? It's unclear...

Comment: OK. I made a codesandbox with nuxt-clipboard2. Take a look on it: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-wuuo5

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sandbox! :)
Yeah... SignTemplate is a plenty HTML with CSS component that contains the signature, it may be not the good way to process but I started Nuxt.js with this project a few weeks ago and I still learning.
I have added a screenshot of my page in my post to show what is look like and wich element I would like to copy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198548/discussion-between-sebastien-serre-and-manutopik).

Answer (score 13):

I honestly don't think npm package is needed for this. Just go with vanilla js solution. It's so simple.

Here's the modern one. It has pretty solid browser support

```js
methods: {
  copySign() {
    //btw writeText() returns a promise so you could utilize that somehow if you want
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.$refs.foo.$el.outerHTML)
  }
}
```

That's it. One line of code.

But if you are looking to support older browsers use this old and longer approach.

```js
//Creating textarea element
let textarea = document.createElement("textarea")
//Settings its value to the thing you want to copy
textarea.value = this.$refs.foo.$el.outerHTML
//Appending the textarea to body
document.body.appendChild(textarea)
//Selecting its content
textarea.focus()
textarea.select()
//Copying the selected content to clipboard
document.execCommand("copy")
//Removing the textarea
document.body.removeChild(textarea)
```

Comment: Most likely should be `navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.$refs.foo.innerHTML)`

Comment: This doesn't work and returns `TypeError: navigator.clipboard is undefined`

Comment: @DavidRhoderick If `navigator.clipboard` is `undefined` on a live website, make sure it is running on the secure https protocol. Otherwise, it won't work. If that's not the case, I sadly can't help you without any specific details.